# how to autoscroll a stackpanel on mouse over like ZUNE?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, modern-ui

I have two questions. 
I want to create an application similar to zune.
Zune has a menu which autoscrolls on mouseover. I want to create that menu for my application. but i don't know what zune uses and how to autoscroll that unknown panel horizontally. i am using modernUI for WPF plugin.

Question No 1: 
What does Zune uses? stackpanel?

Question No 2:
How to start horizontal auto scrolling of stack panel on mouse over?

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Have you tried using OnMouseOver event? Inside the event handler find cursor position and use it to determine scroll direction.

Comment: Zune doesn't use wpf